# Change figure limits without changing zoom

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have a GUIDE GUI containing axes on which I initially set appropriate limits:

```
set(axes,'YLim',[ymin ymax]);
```

At one point I programatically set the axes to adjust limits dynamically with

```
axes.YLimMode = 'auto';
```

At another point I want to programatically set the axes to have fixed limits again with

```
axes.YLimMode = 'manual';
set(axes,'YLim',[ymin ymax]);
```

**Problem:** At this point I want to maintain the currently visible part of the axes via an appropriate zoom (that can be zoomed out by the user via the zoom out tool). How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean with _maintain the currently visible part of the axes via an appropriate zoom _?

Comment: In the last step when changing `YLim`, the visible part of the graph would obviously change. I want to compensate for this by applying an appropriate zoom, so the visible part of the plot stays identical, but the limits of the plot (e.g. what is visible when the user zooms out completely) should be changed.

Comment: I don't get your point neither, since axis limits *define* the zoom. Can you show an exemple of what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Suppose you're using the "magnifying glass" zoom tool in a figure: It lets you zoom in and out (probably by changing limits), but there's also a limit on the minimal zoom factor (which is usually set by setting the limits on the figure, too).
I want to be able to set this minimal zoom factor, while being able to set an arbitrary viewport programatically, so the user can then zoom out if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was pretty simple in the end:

```
axes.XLimMode = 'manual';
axes.YLimMode = 'manual';

% save current "zoomed in" limits (not needed if you want to set other values later)
xcur = axes.XLim;
ycur = axes.YLim;

% set axes limits to desired "zoomed out" state
set(axes,'XLim',[xmin xmax]);
set(axes,'YLim',[ymin ymax]);
zoom(figure,'reset'); % sets and remembers current state as "zoomed out state"

% restore (or set freely) "zoomed in" limits
set(axes,'XLim',xcur);
set(axes,'YLim',ycur);
```

The important part is `zoom(figure,'reset');`, which internally sets the current limits as the maximally zoomed out state. One can then (programmatically) zoom in by setting arbitrary values for `XLim/YLim`. However the user is still able to zoom out manually until reaching the maximally zoomed out state as set before (which would *not* be possible when leaving out the `zoom` command).